# Disable title notification for MUCs on ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is there any way to disable the title notification for MUC rooms in ejabberd on every log in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to update ejabberd to include this commit:

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/6c712b6caaaed35471452612d643f785bfdf11ee

Without this, some clients treat the channel topic as a normal message.

Comment: Thanks, this might be the reason. I probably do not have this commit included.